# Typescript tuple error: Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer

Tags: typescript

I got simple TS tuple

```
const argTuple: {key1: string, key2: string, key3:string}[] = [
                {key: "key", key2: "key1", key3: "3"},
                {key: "key", key2: "key2", key3: "3"}
            ]

const arg:[string, string, string] = Object.values(argTuple)
```

but `arg` got error: `Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)` I don't understand why tuple could have less element in TS.

Comment: Overall, it is not clear what you're trying to achieve with the code, as you're just basically copying the whole array from one variable to another

Comment: Thanks Dima, I figure out by adding an additional  type and reload VS code.

Comment: Has this question been updated according to the answer? It looks like it's been fixed according to the recommendations in the answer below.

Comment: @MiniGod It was, actually. The OP [changed `[…]` to `{…}[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68316394/2) after my answer. I then [changed `{…}[]` back to `[…]`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68316394/3) to return the question to the original shape. But the OP [changed it again](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68316394/4). I didn't want to cause another Great Edit War, so I left the question as is.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like you got confused with the syntax here.

The following means **"an array with exactly three `string` elements"** (yes, the `key1`, `key2`, and `key3` parts are just labels, they are completely irrelevant to typing information):

```
[key1: string, key2: string, key3:string]
```

You probably want **an array of objects with `key1`, `key2`, and `key3` properties**, which is:

```
{ key1: string, key2: string, key3:string }[]
```

… or (equivalently):

```
Array<{ key1: string, key2: string, key3:string }>
```